# How to debug spring dependencies order?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Behind this issue, I want to understand and debug how Spring beans are instantiated (in which order) and how dependencies are resolved.

#### Context

I'm using:

- spring boot
- spring security
- spring data JPA

I added to my DAO security annotations like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') OR hasPermission(#entity, 'save')")
<S extends T> S save(S s);
```

And I have a custom security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, 
                              UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                              PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
    log.info("Configuring Authentication...");
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

Obviously, autowired beans doesn't depends on DAO which have security annotations.

It works fine if I run main method (which use Spring Boot), no matter if it's compiled jar or in my IDE). But in some case (junit tests for example), I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@362b384c to already built object
```

I assume method *AuthenticationManagerBuilder.build()* has been called **before** Spring create and configure my *SecurityConfiguration*. But why? Order of *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter* is set to 100, it should be done before everything else!

#### Question

**How can I see why Spring create other beans (DAO and services) before configuration? How can I check there is no dependency from my configuration service to my services / dao?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `@Autowired` method is going to be called immediately after that configuration class is instantiated (which will be triggered by the security filter being created when the web container starts). That's pretty early, but not early enough for your use case, since you need to be the first to use the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. I recommend you use a `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` (i.e. a new bean) like in the Spring Boot samples (Spring Security will look for beans of that type even earlier).

Comment: That's works!
But why WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is instantiated after GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter (and sometimes after some basic services)?

Comment: Spring Security controls the order of the global authentication vs. the web security (global concerns win I guess). Anything else that gets created early is usually because one of the other early things needs it (e.g. as an `@Autowired` dependency).

Comment: Ok. But if it was a dependency, it won't work no matter the context (junit, depoyed, ...). And actually it works on some case.
Is there a way to ask to Spring to display how it compute dependency tree? I know some tools like intelliJ do it, but it doesn't show me the unwanted dependency. I would like the actually Spring tree.

Comment: You can switch on debug logging to see the beans being created. The order can depend on the circumstances (e.g. an embedded servlet container forces filters to be created early).